# blogdown hugo remove social links

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I am using the academic theme for hugo with blogdown. When a render a Rmarkdown file for a post, there are a number of social links that show up on the footer. I have searched and am not able to find the file that edits these links. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Hugo is the rendering engine, not the theme. What theme is it? Are there parameters in the `config.toml`?

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped. Academic theme. edited

Comment: I suspect you need to set [this](https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic/blob/master/exampleSite/config/_default/params.toml#L153) to `false` in your (real, not example) version. [Docs](https://sourcethemes.com/academic/docs/customization/#page-sharer)

Comment: @alistaire Yes that did it. Thank you for the clear direction on this.